# Why busybox pod keep restarting after completed with exitCode 0

Tags: kubernetes

Created a pod using following command

```
 kubectl run bb --image=busybox --generator=run-pod/v1 --command -- sh -c "echo hi"
```

Pod is getting created repeatedly

```
bb    1/1   Running             1     7s
bb    0/1   Completed           1     8s
bb    0/1   CrashLoopBackOff    1     9s
bb    0/1   Completed           2     22s
bb    0/1   CrashLoopBackOff    2     23s
bb    0/1   Completed           3     53s
```

exit code is 0

```
k describe pod bb

...

    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 29 Aug 2019 22:58:36 +0000
      Finished:     Thu, 29 Aug 2019 22:58:36 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl run` defaults to setting the ["restart policy"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) to "Always". It also sets up a Deployment in this case, to manage the pod.

```
--restart='Always': The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values
 [Always, OnFailure, Never].  If set to 'Always' a deployment is created,
 if set to 'OnFailure' a job is created, if set to 'Never', a regular pod
 is created. For the latter two --replicas must be 1.  Default 'Always',
 for CronJobs `Never`.
```

If you change the command to:

```
kubectl run bb \
  --image=busybox \
  --generator=run-pod/v1 \
  --restart=Never \
  --command -- sh -c "echo hi"
```

A Job will be setup and the pod won't be restarted.

#### Outside of `kubectl run`

All [pod specs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#podspec-v1-core) will include a `restartPolicy`, which defaults to `Always` so must be specified if you want different behaviour.

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: something
      restartPolicy: Never
```

If you are looking to run a task to completion, try a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Last state reason which is Completed.

> Terminated: Indicates that the container completed its execution and has stopped running. A container enters into this when it has successfully completed execution or when it has failed for some reason. Regardless, a reason and exit code is displayed, as well as the container’s start and finish time. Before a container enters into Terminated, preStop hook (if any) is executed.

```
...
  State:          Terminated
    Reason:       Completed
    Exit Code:    0
    Started:      Wed, 30 Jan 2019 11:45:26 +0530
    Finished:     Wed, 30 Jan 2019 11:45:26 +0530
...
```

Please see more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states). And you can try something like this will show the difference.

```
kubectl run bb --image=busybox --generator=run-pod/v1 --command -- sh -c "sleep 1000"
```